# Nginx Forbidden error 403

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have my nodeJS project located in /home/my-project/app folder. I set up nginx cofiguration file like this:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name myproject.com;

    location / {
        root /home/my-project/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to open 'myproject.com'page in browser, it gives me an error '403 Forbidden nginx'. Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to put proxy pass in location `proxy_pass    http://myproject.com:80;`

Comment: @NikolaAndreev I used it, but it still not working.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic nginx config to use for a reverse proxy to a node application:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myproject.com;

    #uncomment for logs
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/; # make sure port matches open port in node app
    }
}
```

The important bit is the `proxy_pass` declaration, which defines the host and port where the node app is located.

As a test, you should be able to `curl`/`wget`/`open` the node app URL (with port) from the server running nginx without issue.

For the node application:

- Be sure the port opened is greater than 1024. Any ports under 1024 usually require elevated privileges (such as using `sudo`) and is not a great practice.
- Make sure the port is not in use already by some other process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After haft of a day working with config file, I still can not start my phpmyadmin.

Problem may come from your selinux.

Please do the following steps:

- chmod 755 your site directory
- chown the your site with the group and user is nginx

  ```
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/<your-site>
  ```
- with selinux

  ```
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/doc(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/examples(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/js(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/libraries(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/locale(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/setup(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/sql(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/templates(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/themes(/.*)?'
  semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/phpmyadmin/vendor(/.*)?'
  restorecon -Rv '/var/www/phpmyadmin/'`
  ```